# C++ random uniform_int_distribution return same values in all threads

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have the following code, I need to have a random number in given interval. Seems to work how I need.

```
   std::default_random_engine eng;
     std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(3, 7);
     int timeout = dist(eng);
```

But then I run it in different threads and repeated in the loop.

```
    std::default_random_engine defRandEng(std::this_thread::get_id());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(3, 7);
    int timeout; // if I put timeout = dist(defRandEng); here it's all the same

    while (true)
    {
        timeout = dist(defRandEng);
        std::cout<<"Thread "<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" timeout = "<<timeout<<std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(timeout));
}
```

But for every iteration in all threads the values are the same

```
Thread 139779167999744 timeout = 6
Thread 139779134428928 timeout = 6
Thread 139779067287296 timeout = 6
Thread 139779117643520 timeout = 6
Thread 139779100858112 timeout = 6
Thread 139779084072704 timeout = 6
Thread 139779151214336 timeout = 6
Thread 139779050501888 timeout = 6
Thread 139779033716480 timeout = 6
```

next interation

```
Thread 139779167999744 timeout = 4
Thread 139779151214336 timeout = 4
Thread 139779134428928 timeout = 4
Thread 139779117643520 timeout = 4
Thread 139779100858112 timeout = 4
Thread 139779084072704 timeout = 4
Thread 139779067287296 timeout = 4
Thread 139779050501888 timeout = 4
Thread 139779033716480 timeout = 4
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bhristov ok like that?

Comment: its not threadsafe....

Comment: A C++ [mre] has a `main`, all needed `#include` directives, etc. Enough so other people looking can just copy, paste, and start analyzing, and so everyone can see other details which might end up being important.

Comment: The true beauty of the [mre] is it is hard to make a good one without spotting and solving the problem along the way. As you remove irrelevant code, the bug has less room to hide, and as you inspect code to determine whether it's irrelevant or not, the inspection can shake problems loose.

Comment: Besides the fact that this is highly suspect and shouldn’t happen, **you are seeding your generator incorrectly**. I don’t know what `default_random_engine` is (and it should therefore *never* be used) but chances are you’re not giving it sufficient entropy to seed its entire internal state, which leads to degenerated results (still very unlikely to produce identical sequences across different seeds though). I realise that this hard to get right. C++ random number generators are unfortunately terrible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a seed based on some naturally random value to your random engine. The below example, that was adopted from your code snippets, works fine with 3 threads:

```
std::mutex lock;

void sample_time_out()
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
   uint64_t thread_id = std::stoull(ss.str());

   std::default_random_engine eng(thread_id);
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(3, 7);


   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      auto timeout = dis(eng);

      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(timeout));
      {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(lock);
         std::cout << "Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " timeout = " << timeout << std::endl;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::thread t1(sample_time_out);
   std::thread t2(sample_time_out);
   std::thread t3(sample_time_out);

   t1.join();
   t2.join();
   t3.join();

   return 0;
}
```

And the output of my first run is:

```
Thread 31420 timeout = 3
Thread 18616 timeout = 6
Thread 31556 timeout = 7
Thread 31420 timeout = 4
Thread 18616 timeout = 7
Thread 31420 timeout = 6
Thread 31556 timeout = 7
Thread 18616 timeout = 4
Thread 31556 timeout = 7
```

Comment: You're seeding the engine differently from OP's code.

Comment: @Spencer Exactly. If the seed is not provided, it will generate the same thing every time. BTW, I updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try seeding with `std::this_thread::get_id()`, the way OP did?

Comment: @Spencer In fact, `std::this_thread::get_id()` cannot be passed directly into the random engine. I think OP's code will not compile. But if I covert the thread_id into `unsigned int` and then initialize the random engine with that, yes, it works fine.

Comment: I used a `std::hash<std::thread::id>` and got similar results as yours.